# Is it possible to make a modal popup with jQuery without any plugins?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering, if there is a way of making a modal popup with jquery without any other additional plugins, just jquery library itself?

Comment: @slash197 jQuery UI is a jQuery plugin - or actually, a set of plugins.

Comment: To those recomending jquery-ui, isn't that the mother of all plug-ins?

Comment: Of course it is. What you need to ask yourself is "why do you want to do this, why re-invent the wheel?"

Comment: I googled it. There were few worthwhile results. I don't blame him coming to the smart fellas at SO :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wish to use a plugin then you need to code it yourself. There is no 'show modal' function/feature in jQuery out of the box.

Comment: Why the downvote people? NOt the most comprehensive answer but it is more accurate than recomending using jquery-ui, which **IS** a plug in.

Comment: yeah peeps why the downvote...the question only expected a yes or no answer. No request for how to do it.

Comment: Because people (like me) come here from a google search looking for some actual code examples. You're answering this question for thousands of SO users - not just one.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you are looking for (well, this has very few code, and does not use jquery)

[Creating a modal window with HTML5 & CSS3](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

Answer (score 1):

Plugins such as jQuery UI aren't magical - they don't use any hidden or restricted browser features or secret APIs - anything they do, you could do manually in your own code.
For that matter, neither is jQuery itself - anything jQuery does, you could do in straight javascript.

So yes, it's definitely possible to create a model popup using straight jQuery or even straight javascript. I'd even recommend that you spend a bit of time reading through the [jQuery UI code](https://github.com/jquery/jqueryui.com) to learn about how they implement stuff like model popups.

The real question though is why you would want to re-write it from scratch. There's very little (if any) advantage to re-inventing the wheel, and many disadvantages.

For example, the jQuery UI developers can focus 100% of their effort on solving browser compatibility issues and making their library work across as many platforms as possible. Browsers and compatibility issues are at worst a minor annoyance to me, and I don't spend nearly the same kind of time focusing on them. As a result, any solution I come up with isn't going to compare to the quality of jQuery or jQuery UI. It's just not my core competency - it's secondary to what I am actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The question is can one display a container of HTML mark-up, in the middle of the the screen, on top of the other content - without the crutch jQuery.

If you asked what the tool is doing, you can begin to peel back how you'll go about it.

The trick here is how to apply the magic sauce that reveals the already styled, yet initially hidden, mark-up. That can be either fancy CSS :target stuff, or simple javascript:

on click, apply the class that adds display:block to overwrite your .modal display:none.

Answer (score -1):

#### CSS

CSS alone can do this for you. You just need to show a div at the center of the screen blurring out everything else.

#### Javascript

To show and hide the div.

Here's the code.

https://metamug.com/article/css-popup-without-lightbox.php